# Java Map<String, Set<String>> initialization types

Tags: java, interface

I have following map: `Map<String, Set<String>>` which I need to initialize. That itself is not the problem. Yet since I want the `Set` to keep insertion order, I thought about initializing the whole construct with `new LinkedHashMap<String, LinkedHashSet<String>>();`, but this forces me to then change the map to: `Map<String, LinkedHashSet<String>>`.

Why can't I use the interface if I specify the specific type at initialization? Or what is a better way to ensure the implementation of a nested type?

---

To make it more understandable why I want to do that, this is the code:

```
private void sortMap(Map<String, Map<Date, Map<String, Long>>> dataMap) {
    Map<String, Set<String>> sortedNames = new LinkedHashMap<String, Set<String>>(); // <-- this initialization
    for (Map.Entry<String, Map<Date, Map<String, Long>>> entry : dataMap.entrySet()) {
        sortedNames.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue().get(getCurrentMonthDate()).keySet());
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

With the help of the accepted answer I came up with this solution which seems to work just fine for me:

```
Map<String, Set<String>> sortedNames = dataMap.entrySet().stream()
        .map(e -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<String, LinkedHashSet<String>>(e.getKey(),
                e.getValue().get(getCurrentMonthDate()).keySet().stream()
                        .collect(Collectors.toCollection(LinkedHashSet<String>::new))))
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Entry::getKey, Entry::getValue));
```

Comment: *this forces me to then change the map to* Why?

Comment: @chrylis _Type mismatch: cannot convert from LinkedHashMap<String,LinkedHashSet<String>> to Map<String,Set<String>>_

Comment: You don't need to change the generic type to LinkedHashSet<String> Just use the diamond operator. You need to only put instances of LinkedHashSet in the map, though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generic types are not covariant, so you can't assign a `LinkedHashMap<String, LinkedHashSet<String>>` to a `Map<String, Set<String>>`.

If you need to force the map values to only be `LinkedHashSet`, then you have to declare the map as `Map<String, LinkedHashSet<String>>`.

However, this shouldn't be necessary as you can call `map.put` with a subtype of `Set<String>`:

```
Map<String, Set<String>> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();       
map.put("key", new LinkedHashSet<String>());
```

Which still allows you to program to the `Set` interface.

---

Here's a simpler version of your code, using the stream API.

```
Date curretMonthDate = getCurrentMonthDate();
Map<String, Set<String>> sortedNames = dataMap.entrySet().stream()
.map(e -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<String, LinkedHashSet<String>>(e.getKey(),
                    e.getValue()
                    .entrySet()
                    .stream()
                    .filter(inner -> inner.getKey().equals(curretMonthDate))
                    .flatMap(subEntry -> subEntry
                                .getValue()
                                .entrySet()
                                .stream()
                                .map(Entry::getKey))
        .collect(Collectors.toCollection(LinkedHashSet<String>::new))))
.collect(Collectors.toMap(Entry::getKey, Entry::getValue));
```

Comment: This would be a solution. Yet I try to use `Map.Entry<Date, Map<String, Long>>.getValue().keySet()` to obtain all the values I want to add to that `Set`. It would be more convenient if I didn't have to put the `LinkedHashSet` first and check then if it's `null` or not. Any way around that?

Comment: @XtremeBaumer I'm struggling to grasp the exact thing you're doing. I'm sure the map/set/stream API can be used to simplify that implementation. Can you perhaps share that code here or post a different question?

Comment: @XtremeBaumer Please check the edit and the remark about your example

Comment: Thanks for the code, but I think that it is not doing what I need. I only need to get the `keySet()` for 1 specific date. Yet you helped me to reduce the code by the inner loop anyways. Maybe you can adjust the stream solution to the new code if thats possible

Comment: @XtremeBaumer I left out the filter, sorry. I've edited

Answer (score 1):

Initialize as follows then.

```
Map<String, Set<String>> test = new LinkedHashMap<>();
// initialize to LinkedHashSet<> when putting elements
test.put("key", new LinkedHashSet<>());
```

You can't use `Map<String, Set<String>> test = new LinkedHashMap<String, LinkedHashSet<String>>()` because `LinkedHashMap<String, LinkedHashSet<String>>();` is not a subtype of `Map<String, Set<String>>`.

Not that generic types in Java are not *covariant* or *contravariant* if you do not use wildcards.